# Using php create a function to return 2 dimensional array filled with Dates of a particular month

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

My requirement is if I pass an year and month to a php function it must return a 2 dimensional array of dates in that month, most time it will return a 5x7 array (rare occasion when feb 1st is sunday it have only 4x7, 2015 feb for example), each cell of the array must be null if it is from previous month or from next month. Is there any php function to do this ???
[image]

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Is there any php function to do this ???

Comment: You're going to want to investigate PHP's DateTime class. It should be pretty easy to do this, but if you don't try you won't learn anything.

Comment: Ok i am trying to figure it out, thanks my friend

Comment: @Brian Gottier thanks for the motivation as you told it was easy and i have posted an answer to my own question :D

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji it is kind of funny that you accepted your own answer, but your own answer doesn't show the 31st of the month for May of 2015, and my answer is correct. I guess no credit where credit is due, right? Anyway, have a good time coding in the future.

Comment: Yeah ur right i didnt noticed that, thanks @Brian Gottier

Comment: Your answer was almost correct but it is not I wanted, because when i changed to `$d = new DateTime('2015 may');` it shows all the dates but the last 6 null which is junes first 6 days is not showing up plz correct it, but my answer works perfectly, i need a perfect block of month, must show previous moths void(null) cells, yours changing to "2015 may" gives last row with just 31st day the rest 6 days of null aren't seen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, I did it this way:

```
<?php

$d = new DateTime('2017 sep');

$last = $d->format('t');

$days[] = array(
    'w' => $d->format('w'),
    'd' => $d->format('Y-m-d')
);

for( $x = 1; $x <= $last -1; $x++ )
{
    $d->modify('+1 day');

    $days[] = array(
        'w' => $d->format('w'),
        'd' => $d->format('Y-m-d')
    );
}

$weeks = array();
$week = 1;
$checked = array();
foreach( $days as $day )
{
    if( $day['w'] != 0 && ! in_array( $week, $checked ) )
    {
        for( $y = 0; $y < $day['w']; $y++ )
        {
            $weeks[$week][$y] = NULL;
        }
    }

    $checked[] = $week;

    $weeks[$week][$day['w']] = $day['d'];

    if( $day['w'] == 6 )
        $week++;
}

$weeks_count = count( $weeks );
$last_week_count = count( $weeks[$weeks_count] );
if( $last_week_count != 7 )
{
    $cells_needed = 7 - $last_week_count;
    for( $x = 6; $x > $cells_needed +1; $x--)
    {
        $weeks[$weeks_count][$x] = NULL;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $weeks );
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This is not I wanted, because when i changed to `$d = new DateTime('2015 may');` it shows all the dates but the last 6 null which is junes first 6 days is not showing up plz correct it, but my answer works perfectly

Comment: You have your correct answer, based on your original question and comments. Don't make me jump through hoops for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i figured that php doesn't have any built in function to do this, so i created one to do this, hope this help some one else

```
<?php
   function getMonthDaysBlock($year,$month,$show_weeks = true) {

        $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
        $dates_month = array();

        $first_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
        $remain_prev_days = date('N', $first_day) + 1;
        if($remain_prev_days == 8)$remain_prev_days = 1;
        $remain_prev_days--;

        $last_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $num, $year);
        $remain_next_days = date('N', $last_day) + 1;
        if($remain_next_days == 8)$remain_next_days = 1;
        $remain_next_days = 7 - $remain_next_days;

        for ($i=0; $i < $remain_prev_days; $i++) { 
            array_push($dates_month, NULL);
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
            $mktime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year);
            $date = date("Y-m-d", $mktime);
            array_push($dates_month, $date);
        }
        for ($i=0; $i < $remain_next_days; $i++) { 
            array_push($dates_month, NULL);
        }

        return getMonthArray($dates_month,$show_weeks);

    }
    function getMonthArray($days,$show_weeks = true)
    {
        $weeks = ['SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT'];
        $newArray = [];
        $count = count($days);
        $iMax = (int)($count/7);
        $jMax = 7;
        $incr = 0;

        for ($i=0; $i < $iMax; $i++) 
        { 
            for ($j=0; $j < $jMax; $j++) 
            { 
                if($show_weeks)
                    $newArray[$i][$weeks[$j]] = $days[$incr];
                else
                    $newArray[$i][$j] = $days[$incr];
                $incr++;
            }
        }

        return $newArray;
    }


var_dump(getMonthDaysBlock(2015,05));
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't show the 31st of the month for the month you have decided to demonstrate.

Comment: It was just a small error while copy pasting the code from editor, corrected it